# Snakemake “Missing files after X seconds” error

Tags: snakemake

I am getting the following error every time I try to run my snakemake script:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cluster nodes: 99
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        1       antiSMASH
        1       pear
        1       prodigal
        4

[Wed Dec 11 14:59:43 2019]
rule pear:
    input: Unmap_41_1.fastq, Unmap_41_2.fastq
    output: merged_reads/Unmap_41.fastq
    jobid: 3
    wildcards: sample=Unmap_41, extension=fastq

Submitted job 3 with external jobid 'Submitted batch job 4572437'.
Waiting at most 120 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 14 of /faststorage/project/ABR/scripts/antismash.smk:
Missing files after 120 seconds:
merged_reads/Unmap_41.fastq
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Job failed, going on with independent jobs.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

It would seem that the first rule is not executing, but I am unsure as to why as from what I can see all the syntax is correct. Anyone have some advice?

The snakefile is the following:

```
#!/miniconda/bin/python

workdir: config["path_to_files"]
wildcard_constraints:
    separator = config["separator"],
    extension = config["file_extension"],
    sample = '|' .join(config["samples"])

rule all:
    input:
        expand("antismash-output/{sample}/{sample}.txt", sample = config["samples"])

# merging the paired end reads (either fasta or fastq) as prodigal only takes single end reads
rule pear:
    input:
        forward = f"{{sample}}{config['separator']}1.{{extension}}",
        reverse = f"{{sample}}{config['separator']}2.{{extension}}"

    output:
        "merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}"

    #conda:
        #"/home/lamma/env-export/antismash.yaml"

    run:
        shell("set +u")
        shell("source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh")
        shell("conda activate antismash")
        shell("pear -f {input.forward} -r {input.reverse} -o {output} -t 21")


# If single end then move them to merged_reads directory
rule move:
    input:
        "{sample}.{extension}"

    output:
        "merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}"

    shell:
        "cp {path}/{sample}.{extension} {path}/merged_reads/"

# Setting the rule order on the 3 above rules which should be treated equally and only one run.
ruleorder: pear > move
# annotating the metagenome with prodigal#. Can be done inside antiSMASH but prefer to do it out
rule prodigal:
    input:
        f"merged_reads/{{sample}}.{config['file_extension']}"

    output:
        gbk_files = "annotated_reads/{sample}.gbk",
        protein_files = "protein_reads/{sample}.faa"

    #conda:
        #"/home/lamma/env-export/antismash.yaml"

    run:
        shell("set +u")
        shell("source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh")
        shell("conda activate antismash")
        shell("prodigal -i {input} -o {output.gbk_files} -a {output.protein_files} -p meta")


# running antiSMASH on the annotated metagenome
rule antiSMASH:
    input:
        "annotated_reads/{sample}.gbk"

    output:
        touch("antismash-output/{sample}/{sample}.txt")

    #conda:
        #"/home/lamma/env-export/antismash.yaml"

    run:
        shell("set +u")
        shell("source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh")
        shell("conda activate antismash")
        shell("antismash --knownclusterblast --subclusterblast --full-hmmer --smcog --outputfolder antismash-output/{wildcards.sample}/ {input}")
```

I am running the pipeline on only one file at the moment but the yaml file looks like this if it is of intest:

```
file_extension: fastq
path_to_files: /home/lamma/ABR/Each_reads
samples:
- Unmap_41
separator: _
```

I know the error can occure when you use certain flags in snakemake but I dont believe I am using those flags. The command being submited to run the snakefile is:

```
snakemake --latency-wait 120 --rerun-incomplete --keep-going --jobs 99 --cluster-status 'python /home/lamma/ABR/scripts/slurm-status.py' --cluster 'sbatch  -t {cluster.time} --mem={cluster.mem} --cpus-per-task={cluster.c} --error={cluster.error}  --job-name={cluster.name} --output={cluster.output}' --cluster-config antismash-config.json --configfile yaml-config-files/antismash-on-rawMetagenome.yaml --snakefile antismash.smk
```

I have tried to -F flag to force a rerun but this seems to do nothing, as does increasing the --latency-wait number. Any help would be appriciated :)

I think it is likely to be something involving the way I am calling the conda environment in the run commands but using the `conda:` option with a yaml files returns version not found style errors.

Comment: What happens if you `pear` command part manually? Do they produce expected output files in expected location?

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy Yes it does :)

Comment: Just to double check, does snakemake use same exact command as the one you did manually? You can check using  `--printshellcmds, -p`. Also, having you tried running it in compute node instead of sending it as a job?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snakemake "Missing files after X seconds" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191168/snakemake-missing-files-after-x-seconds-error)

Comment: @MattMyint It unfortunatly does not

Answer (score 0):

As of what I read from pear [documentation](https://cme.h-its.org/exelixis/web/software/pear/doc.html#cl-usage):

> -o  Specify the name to be used as base for the output files. PEAR outputs four files. A file containing the assembled reads with a
> assembled.fastq extension, two files containing the forward, resp.
> reverse, unassembled reads with extensions unassembled.forward.fastq,
> resp. unassembled.reverse.fastq, and a file containing the discarded
> reads with a discarded.fastq extension

So if the output defined in your rule is just a base, I suggest you put this as a param and the real names of the output as output:

```
rule pear:
    input:
        forward = f"{{sample}}{config['separator']}1.{{extension}}",
        reverse = f"{{sample}}{config['separator']}2.{{extension}}"
    output:
        "merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}".assembled.fastq,
        "merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}".unassembled.forward.fastq,
        "merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}".unassembled.reverse.fastq,
        "merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}".discarded.fastq
    params:
        base="merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}"

    #conda:
        #"/home/lamma/env-export/antismash.yaml"

    run:
        shell("set +u")
        shell("source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh")
        shell("conda activate antismash")
        shell("pear -f {input.forward} -r {input.reverse} -o {params.base} -t 21")
```

I haven't tested pear so not sure what the output file names are exactly.